# Are question pairs of this type duplicates?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have seen several people do this, and I've always felt awkward about it, but most recently the issue came up with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257127/finding-a-pair-of-orthogonal-vectors-in-r4) [pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258833/finding-a-pair-of-orthogonal-vectors) of questions. More generally, suppose we have two questions which are

- made by the same user
- within a day or two of each other
- for the purposes of solving an elementary* problem
- with work shown
- asking for direction and commentary on their work
- for which the later question implements a suggestion given in the earlier one.

The fact that the problem is "elementary" in some sense feels significant, but it might not be: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/can-the-cube-of-every-perfect-number-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three-cubes) [pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120136/are-there-infinitely-many-n3-especially-for-prime-n-that-cannot-be-expres) of questions is what I had in mind
for a nonexample, although it loosely satisfies all the criteria above except "elementary".

My gut always wants to close the later question as a duplicate to consolidate discussion, but the surface-level questions being asked are not really the same (at all). So I thought I'd ask the community to see if you had any insight here.